# Particular ServiceControl : Where to put RavenDB Configuration options?

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I'm confused as to where the RavenDB Configuration options such as *Raven/MemoryCacheLimitMegabytes* or *Raven/Esent/CacheSizeMax* should be placed when running Particular ServiceControl with embedded RavenDB. Specifically I want to limit memory consumption so RavenDB will play nice with other applications running on the server.

Per the RavenDB configuration options webpage [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/configuration/configuration-options). It talks about using the Raven.Server.exe.config file, but this doesn't appear to exist. Neither does Raven.Server.exe.

The only other file that looks like it may be used in its place is *ServiceControl.exe.config* which is used to configure ServiceControl. Is this the correct file to add the RavenDB configuration options to? Particular documentation doesn't specifically go into detail about where they should be entered on their page [here](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/creating-config-file).

Full path:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\Particular.ServiceControl\ServiceControl.exe.config*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct file to add the RavenDB configuration options to?

Yes.

RavenDB used by ServiceControl is an embedded RavenDB, not a standalone server. Therefore the settings for RavenDB need to be provided via *ServiceControl.exe.config* and not *Raven.Server.exe.config*.

For example, to provide Esent maximum cache size, you'd need to add to the *ServiceControl.exe.config* file under `appSettings` a new entry with a key `Raven/Esent/CacheSizeMax` and a value you wish to set. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
       <add key="Raven/Esent/CacheSizeMax" value="512" />
```